# How do I query "where isNumeric(col), and col > 0" in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, short-circuiting

I am in the process of cleaning up some data in an access database where a text attribute that should be numeric and >0  contains non numeric data or numbers that are <0.

Because Access does not have short circuiting, I cannot do a

```
create table cleaned_up as
select * from a_mess
where isNumeric(col) and col >0
```

Is there a workaround short of

```
create table cleaned_up as
select * from (
  select * from a_mess
  where isNumeric(col)
)
where col > 0
```

Comment: Isn't Access dealing with `0=FALSE` and `-1=TRUE` (or in other words: `0=FALSE` and `anyValueNotEqualToZero=TRUE` ?

Comment: What values are there in `col`? What happens if you write `where IsNumeric(col) and CDbl(col)>0`? I don't know whether Access stops if the first condition is false or not...

Comment: @GordonLinoff `col` even contains rubbish such as `204 WK` etc.

Comment: `col like "[1-9]*"  and col not like '*[^0-9]*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on just the `SELECT` piece to start ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a_mess
WHERE
        IsNumeric(col)
    AND Val(Nz(col, 0)) > 0;
```

Then you can adapt that query as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement (what the Access UI calls a "make table" query) to persist the result set as a table ...

```sql
SELECT *
INTO cleaned_up
FROM a_mess
WHERE
        IsNumeric(col)
    AND Val(Nz(col, 0)) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Val as it returns 0 for strings starting with non-numeric characters:

```
create table cleaned_up as
select * from a_mess
where Val(col) > 0
```